# _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml - sharing with views. DOCTYPE missing on webpages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

I have a specific _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml  (in a sub folder of the Views folder) for a webpage and when the page is loaded the _ViewStart and _Layout are used as expected (breakpoint is reached in _ViewStart)

I have a _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml in the Shared folder (of Views folder) that I want all my other views to reference.

The _Layout is being reference but the _ViewStart.cshtml is not (breakpoint not reached) - is this the norm in mvc3?

Also, my first view that uses the shared layout shows the DOCTYPE directive at the top of the webpage (using firebug), however the subsequent webpage is missing the DOCTYPE directive, even though it uses the same _Layout.cshtml - any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post the razor views in question?

Answer (score 1):

Found I had a "Response.Write..." in my view which caused the DOCTYPE declaration not to be printed.